# Dynamic pageSize property of the Ant Design's Table

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, antd

I'm using Ant Design to get a data Table with pagination. My desired result is to have this component stretched over the entire height of a parent container and adjust the number of rows according to the available space. But, since I have to think about different end users' screen sizes I can't simply assume how many rows would be there in a single page, like this:

```
  <Table
    pagination={{ pageSize: 6 }}
    columns={columns}
    dataSource={sampleData}
  />
```

Is there any recommended approach to make the pageSize property react to a screen's height changes dynamically? Or should I just set certain breakpoints manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no antd API for such behavior, you need to calculate it by yourself.

Useful functions to determine the screen height are:

- [`clientHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientHeight)
- [`getBoundingClientRect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)

Notice that those element functions, in React you should access them via a reference, for example with [`useRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref).

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was expecting, but I just wanted to be sure I didn't miss anything.

Answer (score 0):

The way I solve this UX problem is by to set the [`scroll`](https://ant.design/components/table/#scroll) property:

```js
scroll={{ y: "calc(100vh - 250px)" }}
```

With this, the height of the Table will adapt to the user's client height, you'll just need to change `250px` to whatever works for you.